# Saving a model, that has many services, where are my ids

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I have the following model

```
MyApp.Company = MyApp.User.extend
  companyName: DS.attr('string')
  companyEmail: DS.attr('string')
  cvr: DS.attr('number')
  services: DS.hasMany('service')
```

Which has many services

```
MyApp.Service = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  content: DS.attr('string')
  avatar: DS.attr('string')
  smallAvatar: DS.attr('string')
  serviceField: DS.belongsTo('serviceField')
  companies: DS.hasMany('company')
```

Now i have a panel, where the user adds services to his company, and end up pushing the save button which triggers this action in my controller.

```
saveAccount: ->
  @get('model').save()
```

Now my problem is that, with the new services added, i would expect the data in the put request to look something like this.

```
company: {
company_email: "fsfsdfsdf"
company_name: "Elvar's biks"
cvr: 389298498
services: [1,4,2]
}
```

But the "services" is missing; am i expecting a wrong json structure? If so, how should i tackle this?

Might be worth noting, that all the object are created before hand, so the client i choosing from existent services, i just need to create the relations server side.

Comment: Are you using `{async: true}` with your attribute?  It is cut off, can't see the closing paren.

Comment: Nope, i have updated the question, with the missing )

Comment: is that the complete service model?

Comment: It is now, i shortened for simplicity sake :)

Comment: @MartinElvar Why are you defining the company model with `MyApp.User.extend` and not `DS.Model.extend`?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte I need it to be polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to set up a many to many relationship, so you'll want to use a bridge table/model here.

First, create a new model called `CompanyService`:

```
MyApp.CompanyService = DS.Model.extend
  company: DS.belongsTo 'company'
  service: DS.belongsTo 'service'
```

Next, update your company model:

```
MyApp.Company = MyApp.User.extend
  companyName: DS.attr('string')
  companyEmail: DS.attr('string')
  cvr: DS.attr('number')
  companyServices: DS.hasMany('companyService', {async:true})
```

Then, update your service model:

```
MyApp.Service = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  content: DS.attr('string')
  avatar: DS.attr('string')
  smallAvatar: DS.attr('string')
  serviceField: DS.belongsTo('serviceField')
  companyServices: DS.hasMany('companyService', {async:true})
```

From here you'll need to modify whatever backend setup (Rails?) you have going to accommodate this new model relationship.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is correct, i am trying to make a Many to Many, and i followed the guides on Embers page http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_many-to-many. So if i handle it using this approach, i should save the companyServices instead of saving the model it self. And make a the api for persisting companyServices instead. Seems like a lot of work, wish i couldl work the way i wanted. :)

Comment: This looks like a possible fix, of course this have not been merged yet. https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1494